# Can the Taylor series be used to calculate this integral?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

The Wiki article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral)

says that non-elementary (definite) integrals can often be calculated using the Taylor series.  Can the Taylor series be used to calculate the integral of $$\ln\left[\left(\sin(x) + \frac{\sin(2x)}{2} +\frac {\sin(3x)}{3}\right)^2+0.1\right]$$ from $0$ to $2\pi$?  If so, how?

Comment: Taylor series can be used to approximate an integral

Comment: @imranfat Taylor series can be used to evaluate an integral in terms of a series representation.  That isn't just an approximation.

Comment: In principle yes, but...the argument of $\ln$ is approximately $9x^2+0.1$ for small $x$, so it will have a small complex zero near $0.105i$, that determines the convergence radius of the Taylor series around $x=0$. You'd have to subdivide the interval $[0,2\pi]$ and use many Taylor expansions. Of course, other methods of numerical integration would suffer from singularities near the interval of integration, too.

Comment: @MarkViola Oh yes, as a series representation (that means all terms are incalculated) is of course ok, but I assumed here that some transcendental function is represented by a couple of terms of a series upon which term by term integration takes place.

Comment: @Professor Vector - I'm only interested in real values regarding this function and since this function is always positive I don't believe there are any singularities on the interval $0$ to $2\pi$  That being the case I don't believe I would have to subdivide correct?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes a power series can be integrated term by term, i.e. sometimes $$\int_a^b\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k(x-a)^k\ dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_a^b c_k(x-a)^k\ dx.$$ When is "sometimes"? When the series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$, for one.

Thus your first question reduces to whether the power series of the function converges uniformly on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Uniform convergence is only sufficient, not necessary. Moreover, nobody said there should be just one Taylor series, you can have one per subinterval.

Comment: These are good points.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor A power series converges uniformly on intervals within its interval of convergence.

Comment: I am aware, if by within you mean strictly within; it is my understanding that a power series may fail to converge uniformly on its interval of converge as a whole, however, or its interval of convergence may not be closed.